# Display error msg for from date and to date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am posting the complete aspx code though i know that i should not post my complete code to show that this is my code i had posted the aspx code because in this we are using ***panel,ajax etc*** the main thing in this code is from date and to date which is in ***bold and italic*** i should not allow the user to enter from date greater than to date also i should not allow from date and to date not greater than todays date i need to display label messages to the user if from date is greater than to date and from date and to date should not be greater than todays date

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home1" %>
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajax" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#<%= txtTAFromDate.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
showsTime: true,
ifFormat: "%m/%d/%y %H:%M",
daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
align: "BR",
electric: false,
singleClick: true,
displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
button: ".next()"
});
$("#<%= txtTAToDate.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
showsTime: true,
ifFormat: "%m/%d/%y %H:%M",
daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
align: "BR",
electric: false,
singleClick: true,
displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
button: ".next()"
});
});
</script>
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server">
</ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div style="margin-left:10%;margin-top:03%;height:450px">
<ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" CssClass="fancy fancy-green">
<ajax:TabPanel ID="tbpnluser" runat="server" >
<HeaderTemplate>Project wise details & Status </HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPW" runat="server">
<h4><strong><center> Project wise details & Status </center></strong></h4>
<span>
Select ProjectName:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProject" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="183px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProject_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</span>
(OR)<span>
Status:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>
</span><span>
(OR) Domain:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDomain" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDomain_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
</span>
<span style="float:right">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export" Visible="false"></asp:Button>
</span>
&nbsp;<div style="width:99%; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
<asp:GridView ID="grdPdetails" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Records Available">
</asp:GridView>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</ajax:TabPanel>
<ajax:TabPanel ID="tbpnlusrdetails" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>Team Activities</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlAW" runat="server">
<h4><strong><center> Team Activities </center></strong></h4>
<div style="padding-left:100px">
<span>
ProjectName:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectNameTA" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProjectNameTA_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList> <%----%>
</span>
<span>
(OR) UserName:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</span>
</div>
<br />
***<b><b><div style="padding-left:100px">
<span>
(OR) From Date<asp:TextBox ID="txtTAFromDate" Width="113px" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox> <img src="calendar.png" />
</span>
<span>
To Date<asp:TextBox ID="txtTAToDate" Width="113px" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox> <img src="calendar.png" />
<asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="GET" OnClick="btnGet_Click"/></b>***
</span>
</div></b> <asp:Label ID="lblErrmsgTA" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<div style="width:99%; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
<asp:GridView ID="gvTeamActiv" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Records Available" >
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Export" Visible="false"></asp:Button>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</ajax:TabPanel>
</ajax:TabContainer>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

What i have tried is

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" OnClientClick="return compareDate()"  Text="GET" OnClick="btnGet_Click" />


function compareDate() {
            var from = document.getElementById('<%= txtTAFromDate.ClientID %>').value;
            var to = document.getElementById('<%= txtTAToDate.ClientID %>').value;
            // assuming the date is in dd/mm/yyyy format
            from = toDateObject(from);
            to = toDateObject(to);
            if (from > to)
            {
                alert('start date should be lesser than end date');
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
        function toDateObject(dateStr) {
            var parts = dateStr.split('/');
            var date = new Date(parts[2], (parts[1] - 1), parts[0]);
            return date;

        }
```

Comment: You assign to and from equal to the same element. I think you want to change the id for setting your to variable.

Comment: can you show me hoe to do that as i am new to this the requirement is from date should not be greater than to date and from date and to date should not be greater than todays date these two requirements i should do more over they should be messages not alerts

Comment: All I was saying is that I think you want `var to = document.getElementById('<%= txtTAFromDate.ClientID %>').value;` to be `var to = document.getElementById('<%= txtTAToDate.ClientID %>').value;`. Your check for making sure from is before to looks good. Looks like you still need validation to make sure both dates are in the past.

Comment: A simple `if (from > new Date () || to > new Date ()){alert ("Dates must be in the past")};` should work.

Comment: i had done that as var to = document.getElementById('<%= txtTAFromDate.ClientID %>').value; to be var to = document.getElementById('<%= txtTAToDate.ClientID %>').value; but what i need is  from date should not be greater than to date and from date and to date should not be greater than todays date these two requirements i should do more over they should be messages not alerts could you please help me out as i am new to this

Comment: i would be more thankful to you if you post the complete code for satisfying my requirement i tried the above code though i am very new to this hence the reason for asking you is you has taken from > new Date () || to > new Date () but i dont have new date() at all in the code that i had posted it so could you please help me out

Comment: I'm away from a computer right now, but I'll put some code up in when I have a chance in a bit. What exactly do you mean by message? A custom alert? A message next to the input that pops up on invalid input?

Comment: i will explain my exact requirement first thing is i should not allow from date to be greater than to date my from date should always be less than to date,second one is my from date and to date should not exceed todays date suppose if i am running the application tomorrow my text boxes from and to date can accept the date till tomorrow date but not day after tomorrows date and  if i am running the application day after tomorrow my text boxes from and to date can accept the date till day after tomorrows date but not day after day after tomorrow date and the msgs should be like lbl msg not alert

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to integrate what you want. This is all HTML and JavaScript, but shouldn't be too bad to implement. I have an error div where the errors appear. This can be styled however you want, but this should give you the idea.

```js
function compareDate() {
            var from = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;//use your asp id instead of 'fromDate'
            var to = document.getElementById('toDate').value;//use your asp id instead of 'toDate'
            // assuming the date is in mm/dd/yyyy format
            from = toDateObject(from);
            to = toDateObject(to);
            var errors = document.getElementById('errors');
            errors.innerHTML = "";
            if (from > to)
            {
                errors.innerHTML += "start date should be lesser than end date<br>";
            }
            if (from > new Date () || to > new Date ()){
                errors.innerHTML += "Dates must be in the past";
            }
            if(errors.innerHTML == ""){
              return true;
            }else{
              return false;
            }
        }
        function toDateObject(dateStr) {
            var parts = dateStr.split('/');
            var date = new Date(parts[2], (parts[0] - 1), parts[1]);
            return date;
        }
```

```html
<div id="errors"></div>
<input type="text" id="fromDate" placeholder="fromDate (dd/mm/yyyy)">
<input type="text" id="toDate" placeholder="toDate (dd/mm/yyyy)">
<input type="button" onclick="compareDate()" value="submit">
```

Comment: i should not use input type i need to use button and textboxes of asp controls  From Date<asp:TextBox ID="txtTAFromDate" Width="113px" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox> <img src="calendar.png" />
</span>
<span>
To Date<asp:TextBox ID="txtTAToDate" Width="113px" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox> <img src="calendar.png" />
<asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="GET" OnClick="btnGet_Click"/></b>*** these are what i need to use already i have on click event for button and more over my text boxes should accept date in mm/dd/yyyu format

Comment: my from date and to date should not accept future dates that is it can accpt current and past date but not future dates (for both from and to text boxes)

Comment: Yes, this is not meant to be copy and paste code. Of course you will need to change the HTML inputs into your asp inputs, but this validates the inputs and prints out any errors like you requested. It checks to make sure you don't have dates in the future and it checks to make sure the from date is not greater than the to date. That is what you specified. Also, in your example, you used dd/mm/yyyy date format. It is trivial to use mm/dd/yyyy instead if that is what you really want.

Comment: but i need to use mm/dd/yyyy format only it works if i take input as you specified but i need to take asp controls can you help me out as i am new to this

Comment: because if you observe my code From Date<asp:TextBox ID="txtTAFromDate" Width="113px" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox> <img src="calendar.png" /> </span> <span> To Date<asp:TextBox ID="txtTAToDate" Width="113px" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox> <img src="calendar.png" /> <asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="GET" OnClick="btnGet_Click"/></b>*** my button event already had on click event and for which i have some other code in backend so i cant run my javascript code in onclick event

Comment: thanks for helping me till now could you please help me out in this also as i am new to this

Comment: I edited the code to use mm/dd/yyyy instead. All you need to do is replace your current `compareDate` and `toDateObject` methods with the ones I gave. You can put in your asp ids instead of my html ones where I commented above. Once you do that, all you need to do is add my errors div where you want it.

Comment: already my existing button have onclick event and you are also exceuting the javascript function in on click event how it can be possible beacause we cannot take two on cilck events or we cannot call two events for one button <asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="GET" OnClick="btnGet_Click"/>

Comment: Just use `OnClientClick="return compareDate()"` like you currently have it.

Comment: does it works on on client click because my current code is in onclientclick which is not working

Comment: That's the reason I gave you new code, to fix the code that wasn't working

Comment: if you dont mine can you paste onclientclick event in your code so that i can check whether its working or not

Comment: I have the same function name so you don't need to change that at all. All you need to do is copy my two functions and add my one error html element.